# How to track time spent on tests in TFS?

Tags: testing, tfs

TFS (we're using 2012 at the moment) has a functional testing area where people set up test cases and go through them during regression testing or when a feature has been implemented. If something doesn't work, a bug can be created from a test case.

We're looking for an easy way to track the amount of time testers spend on going through the test cases before each release in addition to whether they passed or failed. Could a custom "Time Spent" field be added to a test run? Or is there a better way? I'd prefer not to use a separate tool for tracking time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to track the actual time spent on any task all the time. People would have to be really on top of watching the watch all the time when they start and finish a tasks and of course there are interruptions and distractions.

I flaunted with the idea of using the [Pomodoro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique) technique, which worked well for me when the team wasn't too big.

There is an [Visual Extension for Pomodoro Timer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/de64d8bf-be88-4592-a7da-39fe2b64d90d) available but haven't used it personally so can't vouch for it.

Comment: Between, we used the Pomodairo timer (https://code.google.com/p/pomodairo/) and added a field "Pomodoro Count" to keep track of time spent.

Comment: The testers don't use Visual Studio as far as I know, they pick the tests and work on them from the TFS web interface, so a plug-in wouldn't help.

Comment: Ok, did you see my comment about using Pomodairo. Give it a shot. It's a nice little time app. All the testers would need to do is to record their pomodoros as they are testing. Put the final count in a field in TFS.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is built into TFS. When you execute one or more tests as a tester Microsoft Test Manager ( and Web Access) records both the start and end date time and associates it to the Test Run.

[image: MTM Test Run duration]

You can see this easily in MTM but it is no surfaced in the web access. This is the actual time between starting and ending testing making it easy to calculate a duration. If you have lots of runs you can report on total test effort within a Release as well as potentially ranking PBI's by the test time.

You can do this reporting in TFS with the Data Warehouse and Cube, and in VSO using the RestAPI.

Comment: This is good, but testers usually get distracted by other things, so their time isn't spent 100% on these tests. So while it can track start and end time, it can't track actual spent time.